# Derivative of a Multi-Variable function respect to a Multi-Variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a multi-variable function

$$ f(a,b,c,x,y,z) $$

and I have another multi-variable function

$$ g(x,y,z). $$

How could I compute $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{g}}?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Why do you think that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ is defined?

Comment: Maybe I should have wrote $\frac{df}{dg}$, I want to know that how a small change in $g$ affects $f$.

Comment: The change in $f$ as $g$ varies and *what other quantities are held constant*? Without this information the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: $a,b,c$ are held constant and $x,y,z$ change. The change does not varies in $f$ as $g$. $f$ and $g$ are different functions, I just have to evaluate this derivative. So $f$ does not depend exactly on $g$, they have just the same variables. Sorry for the lack of information and thank you for commenting.